# Whats the difference between Console App and Console App (.NET Framework)?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, .net-framework-version

I am new to .NET Framework and Visual Studio.
On my Visual Studio Community 2022 i've found two solution from project panel named Console App. One of them has the extended information: (.Net Framework).
Can anyone tell me the difference between them?

[image]

Comment: First Console App refers to .Net (Core framework) and second refers to .Net Framework (up to 4.8).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The difference is that .Net Core Console app is cross platform, meaning it can run on macOS, Linux and Windows machines and .Net Framework Console app can only run on windows machines.

Resource: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/differences-between-net-core-and-net-framework/

Comment: https://www.mono-project.com/

Comment: I notice that Console App has .NET framework different from the Console App (.NET Framework)
For example:
Console App (.NET Framework) - I can find .NET4.6.1 version
Console App - I can't find .NET4.6.1 version

Comment: so is there any reason to prefer .Net Framework Console app ? and if no why is the option there ?

Comment: @kofifus if you know for certain that it will only run on a Windows machine. The reason for the option is still there, is because there are older applications running on Windows machines with the .Net Framework only.